# Swift 4 - CGAffineTransform rotation clockwise direction

Tags: swift4, cgaffinetransform, image-rotation

I need the clock hands to rotate in clockwise direction from -180 to 180, but it seems that the `CGAffineTransform` function does the shortest way in the other direction. I tried different ways but I coudn't find a solution:

```
img_clock.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-118 * Float.pi / 180))

UIView.animate(withDuration: 15.0, delay : 0, options: .curveLinear , animations: {
        self.img_clock.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(118 * Float.pi / 180))
}, completion : nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

In iOS, a positive value specifies **counterclockwise** rotation and a negative value specifies **clockwise** rotation.

This is true that it will rotate in the shortest direction. You need the rotations of more than 360 degrees. In this case, you need to multiply PI with 3.

Check the code below:

```
img_clock.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-118 * Float.pi / 180))

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 15.0, delay : 0, options: .curveLinear , animations: {
            self.img_clock.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(118 * Float.pi * 3 / 180))
    }, completion : nil)
```